# ¿Por qué cuando ingreso más de un dato el ordenamiento no funciona?

Tags: c, funciones, struct

¿Alguien me puede decir por qué no corre este codigo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int n_legajo;
    char a_nombre [30];
}alumno;

void cond_datos(alumno vec[], int *ml);
void ingresar_datos(alumno vec[], int i);
void mostrar_datos(alumno vec[], int i);
void ordenar_alfa(alumno vec[], int ml);
void cambio_an(alumno vec[], int i, int min, char caux[30]);
void cambio_legajo(alumno vec[], int i, int min, int aux);

int main()
{
    int maximologico;
    alumno vector[maximologico];
    alumno *vec = vector;

    cond_datos(vector, &maximologico);
    ordenar_alfa(vector, maximologico);

    return 0;
}

void cond_datos(alumno vec[], int *ml)
{
    int i=0, aux=1;
    while(aux!=0)
    {
        ingresar_datos(vec, i);

        printf("\n\nSi quiere seguir ingresando datos, presione cualquier numero, para terminar, presione 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &aux);

        i++;
    }

    *ml=i;

    i=0;

    while(i<*ml)
    {
        mostrar_datos(vec, i);

        i++;
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return;
}

void ingresar_datos(alumno vec[], int i)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el legajo:");
    scanf("%d", &vec[i].n_legajo);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Ingrese el nombre:");
    scanf("%s", vec[i].a_nombre);
    fflush(stdin);

    return;
}

void mostrar_datos(alumno vec[], int i)
{
    printf("\nEl legajo del alumno es: %d", vec[i].n_legajo);
    printf("\nEl apellido del legajo '%d' es: %s", vec[i].n_legajo ,vec[i].a_nombre);
    printf("\n\n");

    return;
}

void ordenar_alfa(alumno vec[], int ml)
{
    int i, j, aux, min;
    int k=0;
    char caux[30];

    for(i=0;i<ml;i++)
    {
        min=i;
        printf("%s",vec[i].a_nombre);
        strcpy(caux,vec[i].a_nombre);
        printf("paso");
        for(j=i+1;j<=ml;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(vec[j].a_nombre,caux)<0)
            {
                min=j;
            }
        }

        cambio_an(vec, i, min, caux);
        cambio_legajo(vec, i, min, aux);
    }

    while(k<ml)
    {
        mostrar_datos(vec,k);
        k++;
    }

    return;
}

void cambio_an(alumno vec[], int i, int min, char caux[30])
{
    strcpy(caux,vec[min].a_nombre);
    strcpy(vec[min].a_nombre,vec[i].a_nombre);
    strcpy(vec[i].a_nombre, caux);

    return;
}

void cambio_legajo(alumno vec[], int i, int min, int aux)
{
    aux=vec[i].n_legajo;
    vec[i].n_legajo=vec[min].n_legajo;
    vec[min].n_legajo=aux;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para mejorar la pregunta, explica en el cuerpo de la pregunta lo que intentas, y el error o problema detallado de lo que le sucede al codigo. Cual es el resultado esperado ?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: @JLDiaz el comentario casi estaría mejor como respuesta. Si consideras que la pregunta no cumple los requisitos mínimos estás en tu derecho de no responder... pero entonces tampoco incluyas la solución en forma de comentario :)

Comment: @JLDiaz la idea de StackOverflow es responder a las dudas de los usuarios... no arreglarles todo el ejercicio. Si tu respuesta soluciona la duda expuesta entonces es(o deberia ser) una respuesta válida... otra cosa es que te sientas espléndido y le añadas un plus

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Alguien me puede decir por qué no corre este codigo?

No está claro qué es lo que preguntas ¿qué significa "no corre"? ¿Es que no compila? ¿Rompe durante la ejecución con un error de segmentación? ¿No rompe pero no muestra lo que se esperaba? ¿Qué es lo que se esperaba? De los nombres de las funciones parece deducirse que debería leer una lista de nombres (y números de legajo) y reordenar esa lista alfabéticamente, pero nada de esto se deja del todo claro.

El título de la pregunta parece algo más informativo:

> ¿Por qué cuando ingreso más de un dato el ordenamiento no funciona?

Del título se deduce que el programa compila y ejecuta, pero no ordena correctamente. No obstante, el ordenamiento "no funciona" cuando se "ingresa más de un dato". Pero esto no tiene mucho sentido, ya que ingresando un solo dato no hay nada que ordenar...

Hacer una buena pregunta es clave para obtener una respuesta. No obstante, voy a ejercer un poco de adivino.

Como señalé en un comentario, la declaración:

```
int maximologico;
alumno vector[maximologico];
alumno *vec = vector;
```

no es correcta. Para empezar, si no estás usando C99 no puedes usar una variable como dimensión de un array, sino sólo una constante. No obstante, ya que te compila, asumo que usas un compilador de C99. Pero aún en ese caso está mal porque la variable `maximologico` no está inicializada. No sabemos qué valor tiene esa variable cuando declaras el array. Es posible que sea cero, en cuyo caso tu array no tiene espacio para ningún elemento, y el programa romperá tarde o temprano al exceder los límites del array. Pero no porque excedas esos límites y el *runtime* lo detecte, sino porque al salirte de los límites del array sobreescribirás otras variables del programa y tal vez la dirección de retorno de `main()`, y el comportamiento errático del código le haga finalmente acceder a una dirección no permitida y acabe generando un fallo de segmentación. Es difícil saber qué podría pasar.

La solución a ese problema es fijar el tamaño del array a un valor conocido de antemano, por ejemplo 100, así:

```
int maximologico=100;
alumno vector[maximologico];
alumno *vec = vector;
```

No obstante, por la forma en que luego vas leyendo los datos *hasta que el usuario introduzca un cero*, el tamaño final del array parece ser desconocido de antemano por lo que esta estrategia tampoco valdría si el usuario introdujera más de 100 elementos (o el número que hubieras puesto).

Puedes resolverlo controlando que el usuario nunca introduzca más elementos de los que tienes permitidos. Para ello, tu bucle de lectura debería incluir esa condición:

```
void cond_datos(alumno vec[], int *ml)
{
    int i=0, aux=1;
    while ((aux!=0) && (i<*ml))
    {
        ingresar_datos(vec, i);
        ...
```

Esto resuelve el problema más evidente que tenía el código. Aún así, no sé si hará lo que esperabas de él, ya que no he revisado las restantes funciones y tampoco tengo claro qué deberían hacer.

Comment: Me refiero que al momento de ejecutar el programa, cuando tiene que ordenar salta error en el programa. El programa debería consistir en que el usuario cargue datos y cuando ya no tenga mas datos que cargar presione 0. También deberá ordenar alfabéticamente y mostrar los datos ya ordenados.